# Windows saving my Python3 module as a tar.gz and not a .zip file? What gives?

Tags: windows, python-3.x, module, setup.py

I am new to Python and I am reading through a book.  The book explained how to create a module with setup.py and said Windows would create a new folder with a .zip file containing the module.  Instead it created a Linux format "tar.gz" file.  Is there a way to correct this?  Or is the book wrong?  Why would Windows use tar.gz?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`setup.py` uses the default compressed format specific to the operating system, which is `tar.gz` is your case.

If you want to use the `.zip` format, try the `--formats=zip` flag.